# What is causing "Parameter is not valid." exception when setting Image from Resources

Tags: image, embedded-resource, system.drawing, argumentexception

This just reported from a user. This part of the program has been tested and used in the wild quite extensively and hasn't changed in some time. It seems it was working for her and only just recently started to fail. Since the image is coming from Resources, it shouldn't need to be Disposed. In my testing (and by examining the code), this should always be happening on the UI thread, so my best guess is that the program has somehow gotten corrupted, leading to an image in the resources that is actually invalid. Does that make sense, or is there a more plausible explanation. Here's the call stack:

```
Msg: Parameter is not valid.
Source: System.Drawing
Assembly: System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Stack: at System.Drawing.Image.get_Width()
at System.Drawing.Image.get_Size()
at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.GetPreferredSizeCore(Size
proposedSize)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.GetPreferredSize(Size proposedSize)
at
System.Windows.Forms.Layout.TableLayout.GetElementSize(IArrangedElement
element, Size proposedConstraints)
at System.Windows.Forms.Layout.TableLayout.InflateColumns(ContainerInfo
containerInfo, Size proposedConstraints, Boolean measureOnly)
at System.Windows.Forms.Layout.TableLayout.ApplyStyles(ContainerInfo
containerInfo, Size proposedConstraints, Boolean measureOnly)
at System.Windows.Forms.Layout.TableLayout.LayoutCore(IArrangedElement
container, LayoutEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.Forms.Layout.LayoutEngine.Layout(Object container,
LayoutEventArgs layoutEventArgs)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs levent)
at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs
levent)
at System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel.OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs levent)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PerformLayout(LayoutEventArgs args)
at
System.Windows.Forms.Control.System.Windows.Forms.Layout.IArrangedElement.PerformLayout(IArrangedElement
affectedElement, String affectedProperty)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PerformLayout(LayoutEventArgs args)
at
System.Windows.Forms.Control.System.Windows.Forms.Layout.IArrangedElement.PerformLayout(IArrangedElement
affectedElement, String affectedProperty)
at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.InstallNewImage(Image value,
ImageInstallationType installationType)
at System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.set_Image(Image value)
at SayMore.Transcription.UI.OralAnnotationRecorderBaseDlg.UpdateDisplay()
at
SayMore.Transcription.UI.OralAnnotationRecorderBaseDlg.BeginRecording(TimeRange
timeRangeOfSourceBeingAnnotated)
at
SayMore.Transcription.UI.OralAnnotationRecorderBaseDlg.HandleRecordAnnotationMouseDown(Object
sender, MouseEventArgs e)
at
SayMore.Transcription.UI.OralAnnotationRecorderBaseDlg.OnLowLevelKeyDown(Keys
key)
at
SayMore.UI.LowLevelControls.MonitorKeyPressDlg.PreFilterMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.ProcessFilters(MSG&
msg, Boolean& modified)
at
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.PreTranslateMessage(MSG& msg)
at
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponent.FPreTranslateMessage(MSG&
msg)
at
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
at
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
reason, ApplicationContext context)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
reason, ApplicationContext context)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
at SayMore.Model.Files.ComponentFile.RecordAnnotations(Form frm,
AudioRecordingType annotationType)
at
SayMore.Transcription.UI.TextAnnotationEditor.<>c_DisplayClassb.<HandleRecordedAnnotationButtonClick>b_a()
at
SayMore.Transcription.UI.TextAnnotationEditor.ShowSegmentationDialog(Action
showDialog)
at
SayMore.Transcription.UI.TextAnnotationEditor.HandleRecordedAnnotationButtonClick(Object
sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e,
ToolStripItemEventType met)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e,
ToolStripItemEventType met)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg,
```

And here's the method in our code where the Image is getting set:

```
    protected override void UpdateDisplay()
    {
        _recDeviceIndicator.UpdateDisplay();

        _labelListenButton.Image = (_waveControl.IsPlaying && _playingBackUsingHoldDownButton ?
            Resources.ListenToOriginalRecordingDown : Resources.ListenToOriginalRecording);

        _labelRecordButton.Image = (ViewModel.GetIsRecording() ?
            Resources.RecordingOralAnnotationInProgress : Resources.RecordOralAnnotation);

        _labelListenButton.Enabled = !ViewModel.GetIsRecording() &&
            (ViewModel.CurrentUnannotatedSegment != null || !ViewModel.GetIsFullyAnnotated());

        _labelRecordButton.Enabled = (ViewModel.GetSelectedSegmentIsLongEnough() &&
            _userHasListenedToSelectedSegment &&
            AudioUtils.GetCanRecordAudio(true) &&
            !_waveControl.IsPlaying && !ViewModel.GetIsAnnotationPlaying());

        _labelListenHint.Visible = _spaceBarMode == SpaceBarMode.Listen && _labelListenButton.Enabled;
        _labelRecordHint.Visible = _spaceBarMode == SpaceBarMode.Record && _labelRecordButton.Enabled && !_reRecording && _recordingErrorMessage == null;

        if (_spaceBarMode == SpaceBarMode.Done && _recordingErrorMessage == null)
        {
            if (!_labelFinishedHint.Visible)
            {
                _pictureIcon.Image = Resources.Green_check;
                _labelFinishedHint.Visible = true;
                _tableLayoutButtons.Controls.Add(_labelFinishedHint, 1, 0);
                _tableLayoutButtons.SetRowSpan(_labelFinishedHint, 3);
                AcceptButton = _buttonOK;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            UdateErrorMessageDisplay();

            if (_labelErrorInfo.Visible)
            {
                _pictureIcon.Image = Resources.Information_red;
                if (_labelFinishedHint.Visible)
                {
                    _labelFinishedHint.Visible = false;
                    _tableLayoutButtons.Controls.Remove(_labelFinishedHint);
                }
                _labelRecordHint.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                _pictureIcon.Image = Resources.Information_blue;
            }

            float percentage = (_labelErrorInfo.Visible) ? 50 : 100;
            _tableLayoutButtons.RowStyles[0].Height = (_labelErrorInfo.Visible) ? percentage : 0;
            _tableLayoutButtons.RowStyles[1].Height = (_labelListenHint.Visible) ? percentage : 0;
            _tableLayoutButtons.RowStyles[2].Height = (_labelRecordHint.Visible) ? percentage : 0;
        }
        base.UpdateDisplay();
    }
```

I'm not sure which of the calls to set an Image is causing the exception, but based on the context, I suspect it's where _labelRecordButton.Image gets set to Resources.RecordingOralAnnotationInProgress. The point is that in every case, the Image is just coming from Resources, so it should always be valid.

Comment: Have just found similar error "Parameter Not Valid" in line 

   ` decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);`

The function containing the line is called repeatedly (for different images) and failure occurs after a variable number of calls, but more quickly with larger images, implying a memory problem. However, monitoring with Task Manager shows no systematic increase in memory use with repeated calls.

Comment: Removed call to JpegBitmapDecoder but still occasionally get the same error when creating  a bitmap from a file  Checked with Resource Monitor which showed no unusual features in memory allocation when the crash happened. Crashes are more frequent when a lot of memory is committed from apps like browsers with many tabs open and when app is processing larger images when it commits more memory. So it smells like a memory problem but diagnostics don't support this.

Answer (score 0):

Could be anything. The Bitmap class is known for generating any type of exception for any type of error, so the reason for the problem cannot be derived from the exception type. My guess would be an out-of-memory condition.